Text Preview in EditBox Component input
I get trouble with the same problem when I trying to create a EditBox in Cocos Creator 3.8. Here is topic link https://forum.cocos.org/t/topic/156310
When the interface is playing the zoom animation, if the editbox inside is displayed, the editbox will not be displayed when entering text, and will be displayed only when it loses focus. This can be reproduced on both the web and Android terminals. The current temporary solution is to hide all editboxes in the UI first, and then display them as needed.
The Label component property of 3.8.2 has an additional Auto Newline, which is not introduced in the documentation. It may be related to this change.
I tried many ways but it still doesn't work. But I found that when I change the position of EditBox component, it works somehow, but I think it temporary. Can you guy explain for me?
    protected OnEditDidBegan(): void {
        console.log('OnEditDidBegan')
        // Lmao. I don't know how to fix the bug of EditBox
        // But when I try this, it works!
        this.editBox.node.setPosition(0, -25) // You can change to anywhere you want
    }


It's cause by zoom animation that make the EditBox scale smaller
